# How to create multiple lists based on value of each element in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I make multiple lists based on the elements in one existing list? Names and elements of these new lists are both determined by the existing list.

For example, the existing list is:

```
a = [2,5,4]
```

The desired output is:

```
a_2= ['01','02']
a_5= ['01','02','03','04','05']
a_4= ['01','02','03','04']
```

I am not sure how to loop to create different list names. Any ideas?

Comment: A dictionary could work since I can convert the keys to list names later.

Comment: Is the 0 in the first position always required? Even for two-digit numbers? Also, do not create multiple variables. Use a list of lists or a dictionary of ists.

Comment: All strings would be 2-digits so 0 will in the first position for one-digit number.

Answer (score 1):

You can populate a dictionary with keys based on your desired variables:

```
a = [2, 5, 4]
output = {f"a_{i}": ["{:02d}".format(x) for x in range(1, i + 1)] for i in a}
```

And then you can access them easily:

```
print(output["a_4"]) # ['01', '02', '03', '04']
```

Answer (score 1):

directly defining new variables dynamically is possible but not very pythonic... my suggestion is to build a dictionary called `res`:

```
a = [2, 5, 4]

res = {n: [f"{i:02d}" for i in range(1, n + 1)] for n in a}

print(res)     # {2: ['01', '02'], 5: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'], 4: ['01', '02', '03', '04']}
print(res[5])  # ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
```

(where `res[5]` serves as your `a_5`)...

---

the messy version that dynamically adds the variables to your global namespace is:

```
a = [2, 5, 4]

for n in a:
    globals()[f"a_{n}"] = [f"{i:02d}" for i in range(1, n + 1)]

print(a_2)  # ['01', '02']
print(a_4)  # ['01', '02', '03', '04']
print(a_5)  # ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer you question?

```
a = [2,5,4]
a_2, a_5, a_4 = [['0'+str(x) for x in range(b)] for b in a]
```

Comment: Your solution will not work of `a` has a different number of items. Also, the first element in each of your lists is '00', not '01'.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this way before. The problem is that I would need to manually name a_2, a_5, and a_4. Is there a way that these list names (a_2, a_5, a_4) could be created by coding?